# Core Data lightweight migration slow even in trivial cases?

Tags: sqlite, core-data

I am doing a Core Data lightweight migration when users run the updated version of my app for the first time. The migration works fine but can be quite slow when the database is large, even when the migration really ought to be trivial and fast.

In particular, all I want to do is add a new entity to the data model, and the new entity is actually completely unrelated to any existing entities (no relationships to existing entities, except that both old and new entities are subclasses of NSManagedObject). Essentially, this operation should just be adding an empty table in SQL, no?

When the main.sqlite file has non-trivial size (say a few hundred megabytes), the resulting lightweight migration can take 5 seconds or much much more (see below) on my machine (OSX 10.10.1, about 2 year old Mac Mini).

In fact, in my experience, the *name* of the new entity affects the speed of the operation! I've been debugging by setting the launch arguments "-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 1" and "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" and it looks like I get SQL operations such as

2015-06-24 11:41:21.711 MyApp[517:14645] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZENTITYNAMEHERE SET Z_ENT = ( CASE WHEN Z_ENT = 9 THEN 10 ELSE Z_ENT END ) WHERE Z_ENT IN (9)

for all entities that are *later* in alphabetical order compared to the newly inserted entity. For entities with lots of data these can take substantial time. Is this actually expected behavior?!

Giving the new entity a name that is *latest* in alphabetical order eliminates the above SQL commands, but the migration still takes many seconds to perform. It seems that Core Data actually duplicates the entire data on disk, as I am seeing temporary files with filenames such as .main.sqlite.migrationdestination_ in the same directory as main.sqlite and with roughly the same size. This seems entirely unnecessary just to add a new unrelated entity/table to the model, no?!

Is there some way to avoid this waste and make the migration fast (creating a new table should not take more than milliseconds I'd guess)?

Any help from resident Core Data gurus would be much appreciated!

(P.S. I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 if this is relevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to use the migration mechanism you are out of luck. Core Data will indeed copy all the data to a new store, and that can take considerable time.

One possible solution could be to create a second, separate store to contain the unrelated entity.

This adds more complexity and is clearly a trade-off but could be feasible. You will have to weigh if it is worth the trouble.

Comment: Was kind of suspecting this... and was already thinking about the workaround you're suggesting, it would be ugly, but should work. Anyway many thanks for the answer! If nobody else comes up with a better way (fast yet avoiding a second separate store) within a day or two I will accept this answer.

Comment: Since there are no other answers and I'm in a hurry to get this done, I went ahead and created a separate store for the new entity. It's not pretty, but it does solve the problem. Thanks again for the help! Accepting this answer now.

Comment: You can always do the copying in the background later and then eliminate the new store.

Comment: You're right, I could combine them as you suggest. But it doesn't really help minimize complexity. Unless of course I end up having to add still further entities in the next version and would need yet another separate store for those! :)

Comment: Also, any comments @Mundi on my observation (in the original question) that the name of the newly inserted entity, when adding to the existing store, affects the time needed to migrate? I find it somewhat puzzling that the migration seems to depend on the alphabetical ordering of the entities...

Comment: @byb Not sure about the naming phenomenon, but I would suppose that the time delta likely has a different, unrelated explanation. It is sometimes difficult to control for all other extraneous variables.